# PHP echo statements blank after page load

Tags: javascript, php

Some PHP variables are being echoed to JavaScript and HTML, but don't seem to appear in the source code that the browser receives. Using PHP 7.2.2

First off, I'm aware that all PHP is fully parsed and executed before it reaches the browser. I've done something similar to this for other projects and never had an issue, so I'm not really sure what's going on here. Some of my code is dependent on user input, so I've echoed some PHP variables into a segment of Javascript so that I can manipulate it after the page has loaded.

This isn't exactly what I have, but it is more or less:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
  ...

  $val = 12345;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("<?=$val?>");
    ...
```

So the page behaves as expected - kind of. The value (12345) is alerted, as expected, but if I go to view the source code (using Firefox v62 developer tools), the first JS line says:

```
alert("");
```

I'm not sure how that's even possible, since it did the alert just fine. This is a bigger issue than this makes it seem, because there are other places where I want to assign PHP values to JS variables, e.g.:

```
var var1 = <?=$val?>;
```

What ends up appearing in the code:

```
var var1 = ;
```

This obviously does not work. What am I doing wrong? Are the dev tools lying and the code is actually fine?

Comment: At the top of your script (always when developing and testing code) enable PHP error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  What is your PHP version and your ini setting for `short_open_tag`? Very old (pre 5.4) PHP versions would require `short_open_tag` to be enabled for `<?=` to work, while later versions would accept `<?=` with `short_open_tag` disabled.

Comment: I've confirmed that short tags are allowed. I'm using PHP 7.2.2 anyway, so it shouldn't matter. That doesn't appear to be the problem, since, as I said in the original post, it does alert the value. It just doesn't show it in the dev tools. I'm using the PHP CLI server command, and no errors appear in the command prompt window (using a WIMP stack, if that affects anything) or in the error log file.

Comment: If it's alerting successfully, then it's in the source code. PHP is server side, nothing to do with JavaScript. You're making a mistake somewhere in your debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, well it seems it's just an issue with Firefox's dev tools. Opening the page in chrome showed no issues, but for further proof, if I put a similar line inside of a function, e.g.:

```
function debug() {
  alert("<?=$val?>");
}
```

Then set it to run onload. It executed as it should have. When I checked the relevant line in the dev tools, it said:

```
alert("");
```

BUT, when I ran that same function again from the console, i.e. without refreshing the page, despite the fact that the alert call appears to be passed an empty string, it still ran as though it had been passed the value '12345'. So this seems like Firefox is not displaying in the dev tools what it's actually using on the page. Weird. Anyway, I'm calling this one a closed case.